# Hazelcast single node fast startup for debugging

Tags: distributed-computing, hazelcast

I'm writing an app that uses Hazelcast. My app is really slow to start because Hazelcast tries to talk to other nodes on the network on startup. This is fine for production, but when I'm doing single-node debugging it really slows down my edit-compile-run-debug cycle.

Is there a Hazelcast setting that tells it that there's only one node so please start quickly and don't bother pinging the rest of the network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable join methods:

```
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="false">
        </tcp-ip>
        <aws enabled="false">
        </aws>
    </join>
```

Answer (score 5):

this will save you at least 3 sec while debugging

```
System.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress", "127.0.0.1");
```