# Hazelcast: How to decrease startup time?

Tags: hazelcast

I've a very simple setup of only two nodes, using hazelcast 3.2.5. The startup time for the first node is ~3 seconds and the second node starts in roughly 10 sec using only getTcpIpConfig. I've tried to improve the startup time via

```
System.setProperty("hazelcast.local.localAddress", "127.0.0.1");
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16487337/194609) but nothing improved. Then I tried:

```
System.setProperty(GroupProperties.PROP_WAIT_SECONDS_BEFORE_JOIN, "1");
```

and this reduces start time of 2nd node to 6 seconds.

Here is my config for both nodes:

```
Config cfg = new Config();
NetworkConfig nCfg = cfg.getNetworkConfig();
nCfg.getJoin().getMulticastConfig().
            setEnabled(false);
nCfg.getJoin().getAwsConfig().
            setEnabled(false);
nCfg.getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().
            setConnectionTimeoutSeconds(5).
            addMember("127.0.0.1:5701,127.0.0.1:5702").
            setEnabled(true);
```

The most time is spent at SocketConnector (0.5s), TcpIpConnectionManager (2.5s) and ClusterService (2s) and elsewhere.

**I would like to have both startup times down to lower than 3. Is this possible somehow?**

If not, can I somehow startup the node, with only loading the data from DB and joining the cluster afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution probably makes the most sense: separating hazelcast service from my own service and using the [native Java client](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/javaclient.html). With this startup is lower than 2sec.